# How can you interop WSE 2.0 and 3.0 in a single project

Tags: wse

As a part of my job, I need to add a new webservice to one our existing projects.  Currently all of the services are ASMX webservices using WSE 3.0, but the new service needs to use WSE 2.0 SP3 because the vendor that will be calling it refuses to upgrade to 3.0.

I was hoping that someone here knew how to let these two versions run side by side.

Thanks

Comment: The vendor should be made aware that WSE is obsolete, and has been replaced by WCF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be unable to run both side by side. WSE 2.0 runs on the .NET 1.1 platform. WSE 3.0 runs on the .NET 2.0 platform.

You should be able to run WSE 3.0 on the web service and have the client use WSE 2.0 on their end. Both should implement the WS-Security standards respectively.